# glmmTMB predictions error concerning random effect

Tags: r, logistic-regression, raster, random-effects, glmmtmb

I am trying to create a raster with predictions for a model, using glmmTMB.
This is based on a model, and a rasterstack.
I converted the rasterstack to a data frame, as I think this is a requirement for the function `predict.glmmTMB` to run.

The model

```r
model6 <- glmmTMB(Used~scale(Road_density)+scale(nonforprop)+scale(devprop)+
                  scale(forprop)+scale(nonfordist_cap3000)+scale(fordist_cap3000)+
                  scale(agridist_cap3000)+scale(devdist_cap3000)+(1|animal_ID),
            data=rasterpoints3,na.action=na.omit,family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

The data frame containing the rasterstack values to predict for

```r
predstack <- as.data.frame(stack2)
```

The error

```
 glmmTMB:::predict.glmmTMB(model6,predstack,re.form=NA)
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'animal_ID' not found

I was hoping someone more experienced could help me resolve this. animal_ID is the random intercept in my `glmmTMB` object model 6. I am using this package, and not e.g. `raster::predict`, exactly because it should be able to deal with random effects. To my understanding, `re.form=NA` should take care of this?

Answer (score 2):

There's an open [issue](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/766) about this, but the workaround should be easy: define

```r
predstack$animal_ID <- NA
```

The random effect variable has to *exist* in the data, but it's not used. (Due to the internal structure of `glmmTMB` it's not completely trivial to fix this at the package level.)

Comment: Thank you @ben bolker. 
What exactly do you mean it's not used? I do need the random intercept (1|animalID) to be part of how the predictions are calculated, otherwise I may as well use the raster::predict function?

Answer (score 1):

Given Ben's answer, this ought to work as well with either the `raster` or `terra` package:

```
 p <- predict(stack2, model6, const=data.frame(animal_ID=NA), re.form=NA)
```

(But in the absence of an example I cannot check it)