# Create a raster with predictions from glmmTMB when a parameter is fixed

Tags: r, terra, glmmtmb

I'm trying to create a raster showing the predictions of a model fitted with `glmmTMB`. I can generally do it with no problem using the suggestion from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736029

However, I am running into problems when I fix one of the parameter values, specifically the standard deviation of the random effect.

Here is an example (that is completely meaningless but explains the problem). Let's start with a simple model that works.

```
library(terra)
library(glmmTMB)

logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
names(logo) <- c("red", "green", "blue")
logo$blue <- as.factor(logo$blue) 
logo.df <- as.data.frame(logo)

m1 <- glmmTMB(red ~ green + (1|blue),
        family=poisson, data = logo.df)
# There is a warning, and clearly this is a bad model
# But it's irrelevant for this example

#predict to a raster
r1 <- predict(logo, m1, const=data.frame(blue=NA))
plot(r1)
```

[image]

The above works great and makes a plot that makes sense.

Now let me use the same model, but let's fix the standard deviation of the random effect to a specific value.

```
m2 <- glmmTMB(red ~ green + (1|blue),
             family=poisson, data = logo.df, doFit=FALSE)
m2$parameters$theta[1] <- log(1e3) # Set large value
m2$mapArg <- list(theta=factor(NA)) # Tell TMB to keep it fix (don't estimate)
m2.f <- glmmTMB:::fitTMB(m2)
# There is a warning, and clearly this is a bad model
# But it's irrelevant for this example

r2 <- predict(logo, m2.f, const=data.frame(blue=NA))
plot(r2)
```

[image]
This creates a plot that is just one colour because the predictions are all 0s. It's a bit strange since there is an estimated relationship with green.

Not sure how to tackle the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: If I replace the `NA` in `m2$mapArg <- list(theta=factor(NA))` with say, `1`, I get the R logo to print. Is it possible that setting it to `NA` isn't setting it to a fixed value?

Comment: Any values supplied to `predict(m2.f, data.frame(red=0,green=100,blue=NA))` seems to return 0.

Comment: Thank you @RobertHijmans . If you set it to 1, it tells the glmmTMB to estimate it. In essence you are just changing the starting value, but still letting glmmTMB estimate the sd. You can see in the summary that the sd is not 1000 when `m2$mapArg <- list(theta=factor(1))` but 1000 when `m2$mapArg <- list(theta=factor(NA))`.

Comment: @RobertHijmans you are absolutely right about `predict(m2.f, data.frame(red=0,green=100,blue=NA))`. I thought of it on my ride home and searching for that I found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by @RobertHijmans this does not have to do with the raster, since the problem occurs when using `predict()` on values. I have found this very helpful discussion: https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/535 which indicates that we need to use the new `map` argument instead of `maprArg` when fixing a value. So here is now a version that works.

```
library(glmmTMB)
library(terra)
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
names(logo) <- c("red", "green", "blue")
logo$blue <- as.factor(logo$blue) 


logo.df <- as.data.frame(logo)

m4 <- glmmTMB(red ~ green + (1|blue),
              family=poisson, data = logo.df,
              map= list(theta=factor(NA)) , 
              start = list(theta=log(1e3)))
summary(m4)

predict(m4, data.frame(red=2,green=100,blue=NA))

r4 <- predict(logo$green, m4, const=data.frame(blue=NA))
plot(r4)
```

Which returns
[image]

Thanks @RobertHijmans